# What's Happens If I Blow Up The Barrier?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If, I Blow Up, Barrier, I Don't Know, What Happens, to Barrier.

Comment: ...what? Your question is very unclear. What barrier? What exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: he means the barrier in minecraft from the end of the world and if he blows it up with tnt what will happen to the barrier

Answer (score 4):

Barriers have a blast resistance of `18,000,003`, higher than even bedrock. It's essentially impossible to blow up a barrier block.

If you did somehow manage to blow up a barrier block (e.g: with mods), it would disappear and not drop anything, as it has no drops.